# Окно поиска для flickr-а на php

Tags: php

Помогите создать "search box" для flickr-а на php, используя методы flickr-а.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем именно у вас проблемы ? Почитайте [документацию](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/), посмотрите на [phpFlickr](http://phpflickr.com/)

PS: flickr не наилучший выбор. Он такую бредятину выдаёт ... Посмотрите в сторону API гугла, правда сейчас оно deprecated (будет работать до конца года с лимитированным количеством запросов)

Comment: Я прочел тут, но не получается. Мне надо вывести на экран 3 типа картинок, по 5 из кавдого, если в search box-е ввести одно слово, то надо, чтобы на экране появились 5 картинок такого типа, а если 2-10.